# Adobe Edge Animation on dropbox

Tags: javascript, adobe, dropbox, adobe-edge

I have an adobe edge animation that I would like to publish to dropbox but it is not working. My guess is that the edge javascripts can't find the edge include js's or the image that i'm trying to animate. Any advice would be much appreciated. This is a time-sensitive project.

Comment: Share a link so people can confirm that's the issue? But it seems quite plausible. Are you using the Public folder on Dropbox or sharing specific files?

Comment: sharing specific files. do i need to be using the public folder in order for this to work?  https://www.dropbox.com/s/jnaix7jrsan1ahl/balloon%20blue.html

Comment: moving to public folder solved the problem.  Thank you.

Comment: @smarx - can you add your comment as the answer so the original poster can mark it as the answer?

Comment: @RaymondCamden I didn't provide an answer.

Comment: Well, you lead him in the right direction. :) THe point is - this question still shows up as 0 answers - so folks like me assume that he still needs answers.